# Determining Bucketing Configuration on Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I was curious if someone could provide a little more clarification on how to configure the bucketing property on a Hive table.  I see that it helps with joins and I believe i read that its good to put it on a column that you will use to join.  That could be wrong.  I am also curious about how to determine the number of buckets to choose.

If anyone could give a brief explanation and some documentation on how to determine all of these things that would be great.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are few suggestions to be considered while designing buckets.

1. Buckets are generally created on the most critical columns , a single column or a set of columns, so it implies that these columns would be the primary columns for various join conditions , as the concept of bucketing is to hash these set of columns and store it in such a way that its easily accessible from the hdfs faster.Thus retrieving speed is fast.Its advised not to use all the join columns only the critical and which is we think would improve performance.
2. The number of buckets would be in exponents of 2. The number of buckets determine the number of reducers to be run and that determines the final number files in which the data is stored. So number of buckets has to be designed keeping in mind the size of data we are handling and there by keeping in mind of avoiding large number of small files in hdfs and few number of big files , thus improving the hive query retrieving speed and optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want  to implement bucketing in your table first you should set the property

set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;

it will enforce the bucketing.

carnality : no.of possible values for column.

if your implementing bucketing using Cluster By clause, your bucketing column should have high carnality,then you will get the better performance.

if your implementing partitioning using Partitioned  By clause your partitioned column should have low carnality,then you will get the better performance

depending on the use case you can choose the number of buckets.It's good to choose (number of buckets) < (your hdfs block size) and it should be power of 2.
bucketing will always creates file's  not directories.